# Modal en el Componente Padre no funciona

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs, modal, react-hooks

Estoy intentando ejecutar el modal desde el componente padre pero no se ejecuta y me da error, como uso hooks para que se vea el modal?

Primero necesito que dependiendo de mi listener de mi evento de google charts se muestre mi modal
Este es el chart events donde esta el callback con el listener

```
const chartEvents=[{
      eventName: "ready",
      callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
        const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "select", e => {
          const id = chart.getSelection()[0].row;
          const name = getNombreEstadoById( id );
          alert(`You clicked on ${ name }`)

        });
      }
    }
```

En donde esta la alerta es donde quiero poner el modal para que cada click se muestre el modal

Este es El componente Padre donde quiero que se muestre mi modal

```
const MexiMap = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <div id="modal"></div>

      <Chart
      width={'1500px'}
      height={'900px'}
      chartType="GeoChart"
      data={data}
      options={options}
      chartEvents={chartEvents}
     />
  </>
  );
};

  
export default MexiMap;
```

Este es mi Modal

```
const CustomModal = ( { name } ) => {
   
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={this.state.showModal} container={this.props.container}  bsSize='small'>
            <Modal.Dialog>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{ name }</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary">Close</Button>
                <Button variant="primary">Save changes</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal.Dialog>    
            </Modal>        
        </div>
    )
}

export default CustomModal;
```

Agradeceria mucho si alguien me ayuda a hacer funcionar mi Modal

Comment: Tienes un componente que crea el modal (`CustomModal`), pero al mismo tiempo haces referencia hacia un div, que es la forma en que se crea con JS. Para entender primero como debes hacer funcionar un modal - o lo que sea -, con React debes entender un poco la forma en que funciona React en sí. Mira [este ejemplo](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#dialog), para que puedas analizarlo :D